# removing the default navigation buttons on the jquery gannt chart

Tags: jquery, gantt-chart

Was wondering if someone would be able to help me.
I'm using jquery.gantt (http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/) purely as a means of displaying data, the control is made via another element on my page. As such I want to remove the control buttons on the bottom of the rendered chart. I've had a search of this site and google and no joys, can someone help me with this?

thanks

Comment: You can find the DIV of the class = navigate and hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
.fn-gantt .navigate { display: none }
```

This gives the following end result:

[image: Result]